# No exit stamp from previous visit to Japan

Tags: customs-and-immigration, japan, tourist-visas

In October I had a 30 day long trip to Japan on a 90 day tourist visa, when I left I received a "departed" stamp in my passport. In December I visited again for 14 days on another 90 day tourist visa, but when I left I did not receive a stamp.

This weekend I will return for another two weeks. Will it be an issue that I supposedly never left the country?

If it is an issue, does it help that my previous visa sticker is set to expire on the 21st of March - two weeks after I'm leaving Japan again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Japan no longer stamps all passports on exit.  Many passengers are able to use automated exit gates which do not result in a stamp.  Even if you don't use one of these machines, it's still very possible your passport will not be stamped.

Your exit will still have been recorded electronically, so they will be aware that you left after only a few weeks.

Comment: They should still stamp imo, as a sort of souvenir. It was fun seeing where someone has been in their passport.

Comment: @Parrotmaster Well, I find extra space in the passport more valuable

Comment: @RiaD What would the extra space be used for?

Comment: For more visas.

Comment: @J... I would gladly do that if it ment having a small booklet filled with official stamps from various countries. Also losing an hour and a few euro's after years of travelling isn't that big of a problem (to me at least).

Comment: @J... "Even if you don't use one of these machines, it's still very possible your passport will not be stamped."

Comment: I found it odd on my recent trip to Japan that there wasn't an exit stamp, and I was a little sad that I wouldn't have record of my trip in my passport.